# QTabWidget set title font of only one tab

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, qtabwidget

I've created a chat program with an Interface using `QTabWidget`. If there's an update in a tab i want to set the tabs title font to a bold font. With QTabWidget::font i can only set the font of the titles of **all** tabs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can only access the text itself. The font of the text is not exposed in the [QTabBar](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtabbar.html) of the [QTabWidget](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtabwidget.html%27). Perhaps [changing the color of the tab](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7/qtabbar.html#setTabTextColor) would suffice? Otherwise, you'd have to override the painting algorithms, which probably would prove to be cumbersome. In Qt 3 it was possible accessing the `QTab` with [`tabAt(int index)`](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/3.3/qtabbar.html#tabAt) but, unfortunately, they removed that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use QTabBar::setTabTextColor() method, like this:

```
QTabBar* bar=tagWidget->tabBar();
bar->setTabTextColor(index, Qt::blue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Haven't Qt close to me now, but the idea is that you should try to set the font for particular page item of the tab widget. Try something like this:

```
yourTabWidget.currentWidget()->setFont(/*bold font*/);
```

Comment: Nope, the `currentWidget()` accesses the page and not the "text" widget of the tab in question.